# Prestashop 1.7 product list refresh for every 30 seconds and update content in ajax call

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have to update product list for every 30 seconds. I'm developing store to sale gold and silver products, so need to update live market price for products. I have a service to update the products prices in background this will update live market price. Now I need to display this updated price in store page. This can do by using ajax method only I think. I have searched product list creating from prestashop category controller.

```
public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        if ($this->category->checkAccess($this->context->customer->id)) {
            $this->doProductSearch(
                'catalog/listing/category',
                [
                    'entity' => 'category',
                    'id' => $this->category->id,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

I could see the option in prestashop like, but I don't know how to create ajax call to get product list on different category id pages.Also I could see updateProductList dispatche event option in core.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  prestashop.on('updateProductList', (data) => {
    updateProductListDOM(data);
  });
});
```

Could you please anyone help me to get products list and update in corresponding pages in shop page.

Comment: I would use a cronjob for this. Doing this with Ajax will give loads of issues when it comes down to the shopping cart. Think about the price the customer will see when an items is placed in the cart, and the price when the customer actually pays.

Comment: I have a cron job to update the price. This is everything working fine, no issue on this. And also there is no issue on adding into the cart or qty plus or minus or pagination in this case prestashop they have solution to update the price via ajax call.(Predefined). But for me if customer viewing the product list without do any changes in this case need to update the price for every 30 sec. I don't know which method I have to call through ajax.